# Using tkinter's Listbox GUI for selecting items from a list

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to create a GUI in tkinter with `Listbox`. My goal is to have the user select from the variables in a list. My problem is I cannot figure out how to save the results of the selection. The GUI pops up and you can select the variable but then it gets stuck and I cannot close the GUI. Here is the sample code:

```
variable_list = ['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6','Item7','Item8','Item9','Item10',
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Item Selection")


listbox = Listbox(window, selectmode=MULTIPLE, height = len(variable_list))

listbox.pack()
for i in variable_list:
    listbox.insert(END, i)

window.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Works fine for me on 3.7.3

Comment: Also works for me with Python 3.7.3 on Windows.

Comment: Hmm I don't know why my pop-up will not close.. I work in spyder maybe it is a spyder issue. Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to just temporarily pop up a window, and then return to non-gui code with whatever the user selected?

Comment: Yes, I just want the GUI to select certain items from a list and assign those item to a variable to use later in the code.